# Changing flex-direction property on a form?

Tags: html, forms, css, flexbox

Okay so I am trying to use flexbox to create a column stacked layout like below. I got that working : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxqlw.jpg

**Problem 1**: there is a margin left and right I dont understand why?

```
    /* CONTACT US  SCREEN WIDTH 320PX */

.contact-us-section {
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    padding: 1rem;

}
.contact-us-section h3 {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
.contact-us-section form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.contact-us-section fieldset {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.contact-us-section label {
    font-size: 1.2rem;

}
.contact-us-section input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    padding: 2rem;
}
.messagebox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#submit-btn {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

**Problem 2**: In large screen I want the input and the label to be side by side, so I use flex:row on the `.form-row` which should make the label and the input line up on the same line. Not working  Any ideas?

```
            /* CONTACT  SCREEN WIDTH 768 px */
        .form-row  {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }


        .contact-us-section input {
            width: 60%;
        }
        #submit-btn {
            width: 10%;
            font-size: 1.1rem;
        }

        .messagebox {
            width: 50%;
        }
```

html

```
        <div id="contact-View" class="contact-us-section">
            <div class="contact-form-wrap">
                <h3> CONTACT US</h3>

                <form action="#">
                    <fieldset class="form-row"> 
                        <label>Name:</label>
                        <input  class="name-email" type="text" value="name"><br>    
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-row">
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input class="name-email" type="text" value="email"><br>                    
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="messagebox">
                        <label id="message-label">Message:</label>
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="39" maxlength="200"></textarea></br>
                    </div>
                        <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">                    
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>  

    </div>
```

Comment: For  first problem : please remove "padding: 1rem;"  from "contact-us-section" class and try ..

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem 1: there is a margin left and right I dont understand why?

There is no such margin in your posted code.

> Problem 2: In large screen I want the input and the label to be side
>   by side, so I use flex:row on the  .form-row which should make the
>   label and the input line up on the same line. Not working Any ideas?

That is caused by the 2 following issues:

1. A `fieldset` element can't be a flex container, so either add an extra wrapper (which I did in below sample) or change element type.
2. The rule for the `form-row`/`fieldset` when *SCREEN WIDTH 768 px* need the same (or higher) specificity than the the initial one set, or else it won't apply.

*Note, the form elements appears somewhat not aligned when screen is wider, and I didn't changed any of that as I don't know how you want it laid out*

Stack snippet

```css
/* CONTACT US  SCREEN WIDTH 320PX */

.contact-us-section {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.contact-us-section h3 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.contact-us-section form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-us-section fieldset > div {       /*  change to target added wrapper  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-us-section label {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.contact-us-section input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.messagebox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#submit-btn {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 80%;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  /* CONTACT  SCREEN WIDTH 768 px */
  
  .contact-us-section .form-row > div {    /*  increased specificity  */
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .contact-us-section input {
    width: 60%;
  }
  #submit-btn {
    width: 10%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  .messagebox {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="contact-View" class="contact-us-section">
  <div class="contact-form-wrap">
    <h3> CONTACT US</h3>

    <form action="#">
      <fieldset class="form-row">
        <div>
          <label>Name:</label>
          <input class="name-email" type="text" value="name">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-row">
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input class="name-email" type="text" value="email">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="messagebox">
        <label id="message-label">Message:</label>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="39" maxlength="200"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code will fulfill your requirement that you have shown in the picture attached https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxqlw.jpg . You can customize and add css for 768px screens according to your requirements .  Have a look:

Added External library: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

```css
.contact-us-section {
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.contact-us-section h3 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.contact-form-wrap{
 width: 50%;
}

.contact-us-section fieldset {
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
}
.contact-us-section label {
 text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.contact-us-section input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    padding: 2rem;
}
.messagebox {
 text-align: center;
}
.messagebox textarea{
    width: 100%;
}

#submit-btn {
   text-align: center;
}

#submit-btn input{
 background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 45%;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div id="contact-View" class="contact-us-section">
            <div class="contact-form-wrap">
                <h3> CONTACT US</h3>

                <form action="#">
                    <fieldset class="form-row"> 
                        <label>Name:</label><br>
                        <input  class="" type="text" value="name"><br>    
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="form-row">
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input class="name-email" type="text" value="email"><br>                    
                    </fieldset> 
                    <div class="messagebox">
                        <label id="message-label">Message:</label><br>
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="39" maxlength="200"></textarea><br>
                    </div>
                    
                   <div id="submit-btn">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
                   </div>                   
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Hope it helps :)